# How to add the configurable product to cart from the product list page

Tags: addtocart

I want to add the configurable product to cart from the product list page itself.
When I select a color from swatch and add the product to cart, It is Redirecting to details page and able to add the product to cart from there. I need to add it directly from list page.

Comment: @FireBear this question can not be duplicate of that question, that was asked later than this

Comment: Ok, then here is direct link to solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/116287/2282

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if that exactly what you want but you can do that with extension that manage `addToCart` function with ajax like this one :
https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/ajax-cart-pro.html
With this your customer stay on the same page without any redirection.

Comment: sorry I dont want to use extension

Comment: @Ramya what do you have against extension?