# Magento 2 : How to display swatches in related products?

Tags: magento-2.1, related-products, configurable-swatches

I added `related products` list in product details page.
I see there all related products list are display but now i need to `display swatches` in this list. How can it possible for related products list.

If any one know please give me answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In app/design/frontend/MyCompany/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml
please add below code :

```
<?php if($_item->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE){

 $swatchBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable")->setTemplate("Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml");
   echo $swatchBlock->setProduct($_item)->toHtml();                           
} ?>
```

And also in

app/design/frontend/MyCompany/mytheme/Magento_Swatches/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="Magento_Swatches::css/swatches.css"/>
  </head>

</page>
```

Comment: I am not getting proper selected options array why ?

Comment: above code only brings a options in  related  product list.
-> to get selected option array in post you have create 2D array like $option[1][141] =red , here 1 is product id And 141 is attribute id of color.

Comment: Worked perfectly  Thanks you so much. :)

Comment: Only the color swatches are showing after applying this. Nothing happened after clicking on swatches.

Comment: Please refer this to add product to cart with proper selected option : 

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305767/how-to-display-swatches-into-product-list-page-into-custom-modules-with-add-to-c/305771#305771

Comment: Thank you so much @CharviParikh

Comment: Hello, I used above mentioned code in Magento2.4 to display swatches in related product but getting below error. Error: Call to a member function getShowSwatchTooltip() on null. Can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: @Arjun facing same problem,did you find solution?

Comment: drop-down option not come form category listing page any idea

Comment: Above code is for swatches not for drop down

Answer (score 6):

In 2.2.5 we're doing the following to achieve the swatches, essentially it replicates the code from the Mage_Catalog::product/list.phtml template where swatches are by default.

Firstly you need to add the swatch renderers to the block via the layout XML for the catalog_product_view layout handle.

In `app/design/frontend/MyCompany/mytheme/Magento_Swatches/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Magento_Swatches::css/swatches.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="related.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
                <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" as="configurable" template="Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml" />
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then override the `Magneto_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml` file by creating your own in `app/design/frontend/MyCompany/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml` with the below modifications:

1. Just below the opening PHP tags `use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;`
2. Load the post data and json helpers just before the main switch:

   ```
   $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
   $jsonHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data');
   ```
3. Replace the add to cart method, adding the form so product can be added via AJAX inside your product actions:

   ```
   <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
       <?php
           $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()]);
           $postParams = $jsonHelper->jsonDecode($postData);
       ?>
       <form data-role="tocart-form" data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?>" action="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $postParams['action'] ?>" method="post">
           <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
           <input type="hidden" name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
           <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
           <button type="submit"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                   class="action tocart primary">
               <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
           </button>
       </form>
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```
4. Then just before the closing if statement add the JS to not redirect to cart if the config for it is disabled:

   ```
     <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
           <script type="text/x-magento-init">
           {
               "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                   "catalogAddToCart": {
                       "product_sku": "<?= /* @NoEscape */ $_item->getSku() ?>"
                   }
               }
           }
           </script>
       <?php endif; ?>
   ```

In the end you should see swatches being rendered and able to add products via AJAX.

Comment: Is it possible to do this same thing with crosssell's on the product detail page? I have created the block inside of the Product Detail Page, and the crosssell products are now showing up appropriately, but I can't seem to get the swatches to render.  I think it is because I need to change the catalog_product_view.xml referenceBlock.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Color swatches are not visible.

Answer (score 4):

To display Swatches along with the product name, thumbnail, etc, just like on the Category product lists, I did this in my Theme:

1. Create this file:

`app/design/frontend/MyCompany/mytheme/Magento_Swatches/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

Add this content (almost the same as the catalog_category_view one), so the Swatch renderer template is available on the Product View page:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="Magento_Swatches::css/swatches.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="related.product.type.details.renderers">
        <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" as="configurable" template="Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml" ifconfig="catalog/frontend/show_swatches_in_product_list" />
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

2. In this file:

`app/design/frontend/MyCompany/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

Add the `related.product.type.details.renderers`  to the catalog.product.related` , like so:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" group="detailed_info">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="related.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
     </block>
</block>
```

3. Then update the `items.phtml` template:

`app/design/frontend/MyCompany/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

And echo the `getProductDetailsHtml()` output where you want. For instance:

```
<div class="product details product-item-details">
  <?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_item); ?>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. After applying this whole related block disappear.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php/***********Display Brand Attribute************/?>

            <?php
            if($_product->getManufacturer()){
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category

                $brand_value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
                $brand_id = $_product->getManufacturer();
                $curnt_cat_url = $category->getUrl();
                $brandId = '?manufacturer='.$brand_id;

                $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $swatchHelper=$om->get("Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media");
                $swatchCollection = $om->create('Magento\Swatches\Model\ResourceModel\Swatch\Collection');
                $swatchCollection->addFieldtoFilter('option_id',$brand_id);
                $item=$swatchCollection->getFirstItem();
                $ThumbImage =  $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_thumb', $item->getValue());
                $SwatchImage = $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_image', $item->getValue());

                ?>

                <div class="brand_bg">
                    <a href="<?php echo $curnt_cat_url.$brandId ?>"><img src="<?php echo $SwatchImage; ?>"></a>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php/***********End Brand Attribute************/?>
```