# Magento 2.3 color swatches with related products & upsell products?

Tags: product-images, magento2.3.2, color-swatches, related-products, product-detail-page

I have added color swatches with related products using this code:

```
<?php 

   if($_item->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE){

   $swatchBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable")->setTemplate("Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml");
   echo $swatchBlock->setProduct($_item)->toHtml();                           
 }

?>
```

It is showing swatches fine but when I am clicking on color swatches then product image is not changing.I want to changed product image as well product listing page.

How can I do this?

Comment: please check in console error or check this URL
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180013/magento-2-how-to-display-swatches-in-related-products/223599

Comment: @SangeetaChandaliya, I have tried this url. but still product images are not changing.