# How to display Swatches into product list page into custom modules with add to cart functionality

Tags: magento2, swatches

How to display Swatches into the product list page into custom modules with add to cart functionality.

We need to display properly selected options with the configuration product into cart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Solution :

**Vendor/Module/registration.php put below code.**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**add the module.xml file in Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml put below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

**Create Layout file for module and put below code in XML file**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="2columns-left">
    <head>
       <css src="Magento_Swatches::css/swatches.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

**Create Template file for module and put below code in phtml file for listing product with swatches and I am assuming that you have  loaded $_item**

```
<?php if($_item->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE){

 $swatchBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable")->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::product/listing/renderer.phtml");
   echo $swatchBlock->setProduct($_item)->toHtml();                           
} ?>
```

**Create renderer.phtml file in Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/listing with below code:**

```
<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable */
$productId = $block->getProduct()->getId();
?>

<div class="swatch-opt customswatch-opt-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProduct()->getId() ?>"></div>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'Vendor_Module/js/custom-swatch-renderer',
       ], function ($) {
        var jsonConfig = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>;

        $('.customswatch-opt-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProduct()->getId() ?>').customSwatchRenderer({
            selectorProduct: '.product-item-details',
            onlySwatches: true,
            numberToShow: <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getNumberSwatchesPerProduct() ?>,
            customjsonConfig: jsonConfig,
            customjsonSwatchConfig: <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonSwatchConfig() ?>,

        });

    });
</script>
```

**Create custom-swatch-renderer.js file in Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js with below code:**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
        'jquery/ui',
    'jquery/jquery.parsequery',

], function ($, _) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('vendor.customSwatchRendererTooltip', {
        options: {
            delay: 200,                             //how much ms before tooltip to show
            tooltipClass: 'swatch-option-tooltip'  //configurable, but remember about css
        },

        /**
         * @private
         */
        _init: function () {
            var $widget = this,
                $this = this.element,
                $element = $('.' + $widget.options.tooltipClass),
                timer,
                type = parseInt($this.attr('option-type'), 10),
                label = $this.attr('option-label'),
                thumb = $this.attr('option-tooltip-thumb'),
                value = $this.attr('option-tooltip-value'),
                $image,
                $title,
                $corner;

            if (!$element.size()) {
                $element = $('<div class="' +
                    $widget.options.tooltipClass +
                    '"><div class="image"></div><div class="title"></div><div class="corner"></div></div>'
                );
                $('body').append($element);
            }

            $image = $element.find('.image');
            $title = $element.find('.title');
            $corner = $element.find('.corner');

            $this.hover(function () {
                if (!$this.hasClass('disabled')) {
                    timer = setTimeout(
                        function () {
                            var leftOpt = null,
                                leftCorner = 0,
                                left,
                                $window;

                            if (type === 2) {
                                // Image
                                $image.css({
                                    'background': 'url("' + thumb + '") no-repeat center', //Background case
                                    'background-size': 'initial'
                                });
                                $image.show();
                            } else if (type === 1) {
                                // Color
                                $image.css({
                                    background: value
                                });
                                $image.show();
                            } else if (type === 0 || type === 3) {
                                // Default
                                $image.hide();
                            }

                            $title.text(label);

                            leftOpt = $this.offset().left;
                            left = leftOpt + $this.width() / 2 - $element.width() / 2;
                            $window = $(window);

                            // the numbers (5 and 5) is magick constants for offset from left or right page
                            if (left < 0) {
                                left = 5;
                            } else if (left + $element.width() > $window.width()) {
                                left = $window.width() - $element.width() - 5;
                            }

                            // the numbers (6,  3 and 18) is magick constants for offset tooltip
                            leftCorner = 0;

                            if ($element.width() < $this.width()) {
                                leftCorner = $element.width() / 2 - 3;
                            } else {
                                leftCorner = (leftOpt > left ? leftOpt - left : left - leftOpt) + $this.width() / 2 - 6;
                            }

                            $corner.css({
                                left: leftCorner
                            });
                            $element.css({
                                left: left,
                                top: $this.offset().top - $element.height() - $corner.height() - 18
                            }).show();
                        },
                        $widget.options.delay
                    );
                }
            }, function () {
                $element.hide();
                clearTimeout(timer);
            });

            $(document).on('tap', function () {
                $element.hide();
                clearTimeout(timer);
            });

            $this.on('tap', function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    });


    $.widget('vendor.customSwatchRenderer', {
        options: {
            classes: {
                attributeClass: 'swatch-attribute',
                attributeLabelClass: 'swatch-attribute-label',
                attributeSelectedOptionLabelClass: 'swatch-attribute-selected-option',
                attributeOptionsWrapper: 'swatch-attribute-options',
                attributeInput: 'swatch-input',
                optionClass: 'swatch-option',
                selectClass: 'swatch-select',
                moreButton: 'swatch-more',
            },
            // option's json config
            customjsonConfig: {},

            // swatch's json config
            customjsonSwatchConfig: {},

            // number of controls to show (false or zero = show all)
            numberToShow: false,

            // show only swatch controls
            onlySwatches: false,

            // enable label for control
            enableControlLabel: true,

            // text for more button
            moreButtonText: 'More',
        },

        _init: function () {
            if (this.options.customjsonConfig !== '' && this.options.customjsonSwatchConfig !== '') {
                this._sortAttributes();
                this._RenderControls();
            } else {
                console.log('SwatchRenderer: No input data received');
            }
        },

        _sortAttributes: function () {
            this.options.customjsonConfig.attributes = _.sortBy(this.options.customjsonConfig.attributes, function (attribute) {
                return attribute.position;
            });
        },

        _create: function () {
            var options = this.options,
                gallery = $('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]', '.column.main'),
                isProductViewExist = $('body.catalog-product-view').size() > 0,
                $main = isProductViewExist ?
                    this.element.parents('.column.main') :
                    this.element.parents('.product-item-info');
        },

        _RenderControls: function () {
            var $widget = this,
                container = this.element,
                classes = this.options.classes,
                chooseText = this.options.customjsonConfig.chooseText;

            $widget.optionsMap = {};

            $.each(this.options.customjsonConfig.attributes, function () {
                var item = this,
                    productId = $widget.options.customjsonConfig.productId,
                    options = $widget._RenderSwatchOptions(item),
                    select = $widget._RenderSwatchSelect(item, chooseText),
                    input = $widget._RenderFormInput(item, productId),
                    label = '';

                // Show only swatch controls
                if ($widget.options.onlySwatches && !$widget.options.customjsonSwatchConfig.hasOwnProperty(item.id)) {
                    return;
                }

                if ($widget.options.enableControlLabel) {
                    label +=
                        '<span class="' + classes.attributeLabelClass + '">' + item.label + '</span>' +
                        '<span class="' + classes.attributeSelectedOptionLabelClass + '"></span>';
                }

                // Create new control
                container.append(
                    '<div class="' + classes.attributeClass + ' ' + item.code +
                    '" attribute-code="' + item.code +
                    '" attribute-id="' + item.id + '">' +
                    label +
                    '<div class="' + classes.attributeOptionsWrapper + ' clearfix">' +
                    options + select +
                    '</div>' + input +
                    '</div>'
                );

                $widget.optionsMap[item.id] = {};

                // Aggregate options array to hash (key => value)
                $.each(item.options, function () {
                    if (this.products.length > 0) {
                        $widget.optionsMap[item.id][this.id] = {
                            price: parseInt(
                                $widget.options.customjsonConfig.optionPrices[this.products[0]].finalPrice.amount,
                                10
                            ),
                            products: this.products
                        };
                    }
                });
            });

            // Connect Tooltip
            container
                .find('[option-type="1"], [option-type="2"], [option-type="0"], [option-type="3"]')
                .customSwatchRendererTooltip();

            // Hide all elements below more button
            $('.' + classes.moreButton).nextAll().hide();

            // Handle events like click or change
            $widget._EventListener();

            // Rewind options
            $widget._Rewind(container);
        },

        _RenderSwatchOptions: function (config) {
            var optionConfig = this.options.customjsonSwatchConfig[config.id],
                optionClass = this.options.classes.optionClass,
                moreLimit = parseInt(this.options.numberToShow, 10),
                moreClass = this.options.classes.moreButton,
                moreText = this.options.moreButtonText,
                countAttributes = 0,
                html = '';

            if (!this.options.customjsonSwatchConfig.hasOwnProperty(config.id)) {
                return '';
            }

            $.each(config.options, function () {
                var id,
                    type,
                    value,
                    thumb,
                    label,
                    attr;

                if (!optionConfig.hasOwnProperty(this.id)) {
                    return '';
                }

                // Add more button
                if (moreLimit === countAttributes++) {
                    html += '<a href="#" class="' + moreClass + '">' + moreText + '</a>';
                }

                id = this.id;
                type = parseInt(optionConfig[id].type, 10);
                value = optionConfig[id].hasOwnProperty('value') ? optionConfig[id].value : '';
                thumb = optionConfig[id].hasOwnProperty('thumb') ? optionConfig[id].thumb : '';
                label = this.label ? this.label : '';
                attr =
                    ' option-type="' + type + '"' +
                    ' option-id="' + id + '"' +
                    ' option-label="' + label + '"' +
                    ' option-tooltip-thumb="' + thumb + '"' +
                    ' option-tooltip-value="' + value + '"';

                if (!this.hasOwnProperty('products') || this.products.length <= 0) {
                    attr += ' option-empty="true"';
                }

                if (type === 0) {
                    // Text
                    html += '<div class="' + optionClass + ' text" ' + attr + '>' + (value ? value : label) +
                        '</div>';
                } else if (type === 1) {
                    // Color
                    html += '<div class="' + optionClass + ' color" ' + attr +
                        '" style="background: ' + value +
                        ' no-repeat center; background-size: initial;">' + '' +
                        '</div>';
                } else if (type === 2) {
                    // Image
                    html += '<div class="' + optionClass + ' image" ' + attr +
                        '" style="background: url(' + value + ') no-repeat center; background-size: initial;">' + '' +
                        '</div>';
                } else if (type === 3) {
                    // Clear
                    html += '<div class="' + optionClass + '" ' + attr + '></div>';
                } else {
                    // Defaualt
                    html += '<div class="' + optionClass + '" ' + attr + '>' + label + '</div>';
                }
            });

            return html;
        },

        _RenderSwatchSelect: function (config, chooseText) {
            var html;

            if (this.options.customjsonSwatchConfig.hasOwnProperty(config.id)) {
                return '';
            }

            html =
                '<select class="' + this.options.classes.selectClass + ' ' + config.code + '">' +
                '<option value="0" option-id="0">' + chooseText + '</option>';

            $.each(config.options, function () {
                var label = this.label,
                    attr = ' value="' + this.id + '" option-id="' + this.id + '"';

                if (!this.hasOwnProperty('products') || this.products.length <= 0) {
                    attr += ' option-empty="true"';
                }

                html += '<option ' + attr + '>' + label + '</option>';
            });

            html += '</select>';

            return html;
        },

        _RenderFormInput: function (config, productId) {
            return '<input class="' + this.options.classes.attributeInput + ' super-attribute-select" ' +
                'name="super_attribute['+productId+'][' + config.id + ']" ' +
                'type="text" ' +
                'value="" ' +
                'data-selector="super_attribute['+productId+'][' + config.id + ']" ' +
                'data-validate="{required:true}" ' +
                'aria-required="true" ' +
                'aria-invalid="true" ' +
                'style="visibility: hidden; position:absolute; left:-1000px">';
        },

        _EventListener: function () {

            var $widget = this;

            $widget.element.on('click', '.' + this.options.classes.optionClass, function () {
                return $widget._OnClick($(this), $widget);
            });

            $widget.element.on('change', '.' + this.options.classes.selectClass, function () {
                return $widget._OnChange($(this), $widget);
            });

            $widget.element.on('click', '.' + this.options.classes.moreButton, function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                return $widget._OnMoreClick($(this));
            });
        },

        _OnClick: function ($this, $widget) {
            var $parent = $this.parents('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass),
                $label = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeSelectedOptionLabelClass),
                attributeId = $parent.attr('attribute-id'),
                $input = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeInput);

            if ($this.hasClass('disabled')) {
                return;
            }

            if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
                $parent.removeAttr('option-selected').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $input.val('');
                $label.text('');
            } else {
                $parent.attr('option-selected', $this.attr('option-id')).find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $label.text($this.attr('option-label'));
                $input.val($this.attr('option-id'));
                $this.addClass('selected');
            }

            $widget._Rebuild();

            if ($widget.element.closest('li').find('.item-price').length) {
                $widget._UpdatePrice();
            }
            $input.trigger('change');
        },

        _OnChange: function ($this, $widget) {
            var $parent = $this.parents('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass),
                attributeId = $parent.attr('attribute-id'),
                $input = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeInput);

            if ($this.val() > 0) {
                $parent.attr('option-selected', $this.val());
                $input.val($this.val());
            } else {
                $parent.removeAttr('option-selected');
                $input.val('');
            }

            $widget._Rebuild();
            $widget._UpdatePrice();
            $input.trigger('change');
        },

        _OnMoreClick: function ($this) {
            $this.nextAll().show();
            $this.blur().remove();
        },

        _Rewind: function (controls) {
            controls.find('div[option-id], option[option-id]').removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
            controls.find('div[option-empty], option[option-empty]').attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
        },

        _Rebuild: function () {

            var $widget = this,
                controls = $widget.element.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass + '[attribute-id]'),
                selected = controls.filter('[option-selected]');

            // Enable all options
            $widget._Rewind(controls);

            // done if nothing selected
            if (selected.size() <= 0) {
                return;
            }

            // Disable not available options
            controls.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    id = $this.attr('attribute-id'),
                    products = $widget._CalcProducts(id);

                if (selected.size() === 1 && selected.first().attr('attribute-id') === id) {
                    return;
                }

                $this.find('[option-id]').each(function () {
                    var $element = $(this),
                        option = $element.attr('option-id');

                    if (!$widget.optionsMap.hasOwnProperty(id) || !$widget.optionsMap[id].hasOwnProperty(option) ||
                        $element.hasClass('selected') ||
                        $element.is(':selected')) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (_.intersection(products, $widget.optionsMap[id][option].products).length <= 0) {
                        $element.attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
                    }
                });
            });
        },

        _CalcProducts: function ($skipAttributeId) {
            var $widget = this,
                products = [];

            // Generate intersection of products
            $widget.element.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass + '[option-selected]').each(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('attribute-id'),
                    option = $(this).attr('option-selected');

                if ($skipAttributeId !== undefined && $skipAttributeId === id) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!$widget.optionsMap.hasOwnProperty(id) || !$widget.optionsMap[id].hasOwnProperty(option)) {
                    return;
                }

                if (products.length === 0) {
                    products = $widget.optionsMap[id][option].products;
                } else {
                    products = _.intersection(products, $widget.optionsMap[id][option].products);
                }
            });

            return products;
        },

        _UpdatePrice: function () {
            var $widget = this,
                $product = $widget.element.closest('li'),
                options = _.object(_.keys($widget.optionsMap), {}),
                result;

            $widget.element.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass + '[option-selected]').each(function () {
                var attributeId = $(this).attr('attribute-id');

                options[attributeId] = $(this).attr('option-selected');
            });

            result = $widget.options.customjsonConfig.optionPrices[_.findKey($widget.options.customjsonConfig.index, options)];

            if (result) {
                $product.find('.item-price').attr('data-price-amount', result.finalPrice.amount);
                $product.find('.related-checkbox').attr('data-price-amount', result.finalPrice.amount).change();
            }
        }
    });

    return $.vendor.customSwatchRenderer;
});
```

**Create Controller for add to cart in Vendor/Module/Controller/Cart/Add.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Cart;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 

class Add extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    */

    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $formKey;   
    protected $cart;
    protected $_productRepository;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost('custom_products');
        $option = $this->getRequest()->getPost('options');
        $super_attribute = $this->getRequest()->getPost('super_attribute');
        try {
            $form_key = $this->formKey->getFormKey();

            foreach($post as $productId){
                //Load the product based on productID   

                $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);  
                if(!empty($option))
                {

                   $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $form_key,
                    'product' => $productId, //product Id
                    'qty'   =>1, //quantity of product                
                    'options' => $option
                    );
                }
                else if(!empty($super_attribute[$productId]))
                {

                   $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $form_key,
                    'product' => $productId, //product Id
                    'qty'   =>1, //quantity of product                
                    'super_attribute' => $super_attribute[$productId]
                    );
                }
                else {
                    $params = array(
                        'form_key' => $form_key,
                        'product' => $productId, //product Id
                        'qty'   =>1 //quantity of product                
                    );
                }   

                $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);               

            }
            $this->cart->save();           

            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Add to cart successfully.'));

        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, $e->getMessage());
        }    
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
?>
```