# How to define if product has swatches?

Tags: configurable-product, swatches, configurable-swatches

Magento 2.4.4.
I am getting some configurable product model.

```
$product = $block->getProduct();
```

I need to determine, whether this product has swatches or not.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I Hope this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305767/how-to-display-swatches-into-product-list-page-into-custom-modules-with-add-to-c) will help you.