# How to show swatches in related product in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product

Like the title i just wanna show swatches in related product witch each other, anny ideas ? Thank you all [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2 : How to display swatches in related products?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180013/magento-2-how-to-display-swatches-in-related-products)

Comment: it's not working for me :(( @Ankit

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzXBzsP3NIY&ab_channel=RoelVandePaar
If it is not working post your code

Comment: @Ankit okey let me try, tks u